# Activiti process instance is not getting suspended by using suspendProcessInstanceById java api

Tags: activiti

Issue in short : Using Below Activiti api process instance is not getting suspended. `Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getRuntimeService().suspendProcessInstanceById(execution.getProcessInstanceId());`

More details : I have few service task in my activiti process definition. I want to call rest webservice from it. For this purpose i written one java delegate class which give call to rest webservice. I want to suspend current process instance if anything goes wrong in rest call (like service is down) and resume that process instance after some time. In java delegate class implementation i am using below api to suspend process instance but process instance is not getting suspended.

```
Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getRuntimeService().suspendProcessInstanceById(execution.getProcessInstanceId());
```

I tried by making task asynchronous but no luck.
Also i given try with actviti 5.19 version and 6.0 but facing same issue. Only difference is that with 5.19 version it works sometime but not consistently.
Please provide solution, any alternative way if knows

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `JavaDelegate`, I used `ActivityBehavior` interface issue got resolved.